# Ubuntu Saucy - Infinality

Tags: package-management, 13.10

Is there any repositories with Infinality for Ubuntu Saucy? In Ubuntu 13.04 I have used [this](https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/ppa) but now there is no packages for Ubuntu Saucy.

Comment: You should wait a few days and see if the PPA is updated with saucy packages. Saucy is still fresh out of Canonical, so not everything may be packaged yet.

Answer (score 1):

PPA maintainer here. It's updated now.